# Doing a COUNT DISTINCT on a concatenated field and limiting to >= 2

Tags: sql, oracle

I’m pretty new to SQL and especially to Oracle. I need to count by the concatenated field “UNIQUE_PROVIDER_PATIENT_COMBO” AND include only those records having >= 2 – in other words, only show those where the same provider/patient combo exists more than once. I’m close, but can’t get all the way there. I’ve tried doing this with a common table expression as well, and just not getting the last step. Base query is below. Help would be much appreciated!

```
SELECT DISTINCT
pat.PAT_NAME "PATIENT"
,pat.PAT_ID
,prov.PROV_NAME "VISIT PROVIDER"
,prov.PROV_ID
,enc.CONTACT_DATE "VISIT DATE"
,prov.PROV_NAME || ' ' || '+' || ' ' || pat.PAT_NAME   AS "PROVIDER + PATIENT"
,prov.PROV_ID || ' ' || '+' || ' ' || pat.PAT_ID   AS "UNIQUE_PROVIDER_PATIENT_COMBO"

FROM  
CMRCL_TFH.PATIENT pat 
INNER JOIN CMRCL_TFH.PAT_ENC enc ON pat.PAT_ID = enc.PAT_ID
INNER JOIN CMRCL_TFH.CLARITY_DEP dep ON enc.DEPARTMENT_ID =   dep.DEPARTMENT_ID
INNER JOIN CLARITY_SER prov ON enc.VISIT_PROV_ID = prov.PROV_ID

WHERE 
enc.CONTACT_DATE BETWEEN '01-JAN-18' AND '31-MAR-18'

GROUP BY 
pat.PAT_NAME
, pat.PAT_ID
, prov.PROV_NAME
, prov.PROV_ID
, enc.CONTACT_DATE
, prov.PROV_NAME || ' ' || '+' || ' ' || pat.PAT_NAME
, prov.PROV_ID || ' ' || '+' || ' ' || pat.PAT_ID

ORDER BY "PROVIDER + PATIENT";
```

Comment: Not sure if this applies to Oracle, but SQL Server has a `HAVING` clause - so you can add to your `GROUP BY` a `HAVING COUNT(fieldName) >= 2` - there should be equivalent syntax for Oracle

Comment: @CoolBots `HAVING` is core SQL. All SQL engines supporting `GROUP BY` will also support `HAVING`. I wouldn't even consider them SQL engines unless they support both, because without that support, they are just SQL imposters ;-)

Comment: I tried doing this with a HAVING clause, but since the column is aliased, I'm not getting a result. I tried: having count("alias") >= 2, and having count([alias]) >=2, etc. but it's not working.

Comment: You can repeat the expression in the `HAVING` clause, e.g. `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT prov.PROV_ID || ' ' || '+' || ' ' || pat.PAT_ID) >= 2`

Comment: @Andreas, thanks, that's good to know! I agree it certainly should be core SQL!

Comment: Tried this Andreas, thank you. Getting error:  ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 1

Comment: You have to add all other columns in the group by section. You can't use an aggregation function and not inform which columns you want to aggregate. You can also use window functions...

Answer (score 0):

Just use two aggregations:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT prov.PROV_NAME || ' ' || '+' || ' ' || pat.PAT_NAME as provider_patient
      FROM CMRCL_TFH.PATIENT pat INNER JOIN
           CMRCL_TFH.PAT_ENC enc
           ON pat.PAT_ID = enc.PAT_ID INNER JOIN
           CMRCL_TFH.CLARITY_DEP dep
           ON enc.DEPARTMENT_ID = dep.DEPARTMENT_ID INNER JOIN
           CLARITY_SER prov 
           ON enc.VISIT_PROV_ID = prov.PROV_ID
      WHERE enc.CONTACT_DATE BETWEEN DATE'2018-01-01' AND DATE'2018-03-31'
      GROUP BY prov.PROV_NAME || ' ' || '+' || ' ' || pat.PAT_NAME
      HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
     ) pp;
```